# What is the Swift equivalent of Java's Random class (isolated PRNG)

Tags: java, swift, random

Most discussions of random number generation in Swift talk about arc4random() and other standard C functions that produce a global sequences of random numbers.  In some cases it is useful to have an isolated pseudorandom number generator that provides separate, reproducible streams of numbers.  e.g. in a game you may wish to have a reproducible random sequences for two aspects of the game and the order in which the two are called should not change the respective streams.

Comment: So... uhh... what's the question here?

Comment: Answering your own question is explicitly encouraged (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but you have to post a real question (only) as the question, and the answer as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer as provided by OP

The rand_r() function accomplishes this by operating on its own seed value to maintain state.  Here is a simple example of how one could mimic the Java Random class with this.

```
/** Java style PRNG */
public class Random
{
    var seed : UInt32 = 0

    init( _ seed : UInt32 ) {
        self.seed = seed
    }

    /** float 0-1.0 */
    public func nextFloat() -> Float {
        return Float(rand_r(&seed)) / Float(INT32_MAX);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should probably make this CW.

Comment: BTW if you didn't know, CW stands for "Community Wiki".

Comment: Does that mean that function's state is just 32 bits long? So it works in a loop of 4 billion states, and that's it? Wow...

Answer (score 0):

The rand_r() function accomplishes this by operating on its own seed value to maintain state.  Here is a simple example of how one could mimic the Java Random class with this.

```
/** Java style PRNG */
public class Random
{
    var seed : UInt32 = 0

    init( _ seed : UInt32 ) {
        self.seed = seed
    }

    /** float 0-1.0 */
    public func nextFloat() -> Float {
        return Float(rand_r(&seed)) / Float(INT32_MAX);
    }

}
```